# didn't redirect to next parameter? django

Tags: django, django-views, django-login

my authentication view:

```
    class LoginView(auth_views.LoginView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = 'event/login.html'
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        next_url = self.request.POST.get('next', reverse('event:create_table'))
        response = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        redirect_url = reverse('event:login') + f"?next={next_url}"
        
        #ログインできたら、前の画面・ホーム画面に戻る
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect(next_url)
        else:
            return redirect(redirect_url)
        
        return response
    
    class RegisterView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = RegisterForm
    template_name = 'event/register.html'
    
    #登録できたら、前の画面・ホーム画面に戻る
    def form_invalid(self, form):
        messages.error(self.request, '会員登録に失敗しました。正しい情報を入力してください。')
        next_url = self.request.GET.get('next', reverse('event:create_table'))
        return redirect(next_url)
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        messages.success(self.request, '会員登録完了!ログインしてください')
        next_url = self.request.GET.get('next', reverse('event:create_table'))
        return next_url
```

my login html:

```
    <h1>ログイン</h1>

    <form action="{% url 'event:login' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
  
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.GET.next }}">

    <!-- ログインボタン -->
      <button type="submit" class="submit-button" id="submit">ログイン</button>  
  
    </form>
```

My problem was it didn't redirect to the previous page after login. It worked before this but suddenly it didn't. The url included the previous url in the next parameter but after submitting the form, it redirect to the default event:create_table. Can someone give me any idea why did this happen??

i tried changing to request.POST.get('next', reverse('event:create_table')) and it kinda seems to work, but previously i use request.POST it didn't work so now I am confused. And in my test case, request.POST didnt redirect to the correct url but request.GET did so I don't know my django website couldn't work properly

Answer (score 0):

You make a POST request, so the next will be in the `request.POST`. You can pass in in the path by setting that as `action=..`:

```
<form action="{% url 'event:login' %}?next={{ request.GET.next|urlencode }}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <!-- ログインボタン -->
      <button type="submit" class="submit-button" id="submit">ログイン</button>  
</form>
```

You *don't* need to subclass the `LoginView` to handle the request then.